# Where is the third data volume for The Frightened Engineer?

Tags: the-outer-worlds

I'm trying to get all the volumes of "A Young Spacer's Guide to Mechanical Engineering" for Thomas Kemp, but I'm having trouble finding the third volume.

I've gotten this hint:

> It was seen in the cannery

But I still haven't noticed the data volume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find the final book inside the Geothermal Plant. Follow the path through the plant until you hear Higgins screaming in the silo section. Drop to the lowest level, you’ll find the book resting against a nearby wall.

I think I read an entry at a terminal about someone taking it to the geothermal plant after reading it, that's the hint about searching in the cannery. I picked it up during the main mission for finding the equipment for the ship.

[image]

Comment: [Here's the location on the a map](https://mapgenie.io/the-outer-worlds/maps/emerald-vale?locationIds=18244)